# Using global constant or enums without specifying class names

Tags: c#, .net, enums, constants

I'm *migrating* a `C` program to `C#` that simply listens serial port and decodes incoming bytes to build the command packets. So I have some constant variables and typedefs in a header file named "protocol.h". I need to use these constant variables and typedefs in my C# classes.

I have created a `"protocol.cs"` file that will keep the constants.

```
//protocol.cs file

namespace SerialPort_Listener
{
    class constants
    {
        const byte PCK_SOP1 = 0xAA;
        const byte PCK_SOP2 = 0xCC;
        const byte PCK_EOP = 0x55;

        public enum CMD_IDs
        {
            ID_READ_VAR = 0,
            ID_WRITE_VAR,
            ID_READ_MEM,
            ID_WRITE_MEM,

            ID_COUNT    
        };

        public enum RET_VALs
        {
            PCK_READY = 0,
            PCK_NOT_RDY,
            PCK_INV_ID,
            PCK_CHK_ERR,

            VAL_COUNT
        };
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the `RET_VALs` enumeration as a returning type of a method in another class file. But I need to use it like this:

```
//decoder.cs file

namespace SerialPort_Listener
{
    class protocol
    {
        // C version: RET_VALs decode(uint8 recByte){}
        public constants.RET_VALs decode(byte recByte) 
        {
            // C version: if(recByte == PCK_SOP1){}
            if (recByte == constants.PCK_SOP1)         
            {
                // C version: return PCK_NOT_RDY; 
                return constants.RET_VALs.PCK_NOT_RDY; 
            }
        }        
    }       
}
```

Is there a better way to **skip referencing** the class name `constants` every time? I have searched for the posts about the ways of defining constants in different files but most of them were using this method.

**Edit:** I guess there was a confusion. I will need to use these in all of my other cs files too. So moving the enums out of the class is not enough since I still won't be able to access them from another file.

Comment: Just don't put them into the `constants` class in the first place?

Comment: You could declare your constants class as static

Comment: Why is it a big deal to include the class name? Having the class name in there tells me--as a developer who didn't write the code--where the particular constant lives without me having to mouse over or "Go to definition" to do the same.

Comment: @nvoigt but I will need to use them in another file too. maybe all of my cs files will use these constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for `using static` construction:

```
using static SerialPort_Listener.constants;
using static SerialPort_Listener.constants.RET_VALs;
```

Then you can put

```
// Now, there's no need to mention "constants" class here
if (recByte == PCK_SOP1)               
{
    // as well as the enum  
    return PCK_NOT_RDY;               
}
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know the using static thing

Comment: I had actually tried `SerialPort_Listener.constants` but that didn't try. Thanks for noticing the `static` keyword!

Answer (score 4):

An Enum doesnt need to be in a class :

```
namespace SerialPort_Listener
{
    class constants
    {
        const byte PCK_SOP1 = 0xAA;
        const byte PCK_SOP2 = 0xCC;
        const byte PCK_EOP = 0x55;
    }

    public enum CMD_IDs
    {
       ID_READ_VAR = 0,
       ID_WRITE_VAR,
       ID_READ_MEM,
       ID_WRITE_MEM,
       ID_COUNT    
   };

   public enum RET_VALs
   {
       PCK_READY = 0,
       PCK_NOT_RDY,
       PCK_INV_ID,
       PCK_CHK_ERR,
       VAL_COUNT
    };
}
```

You can even have a separated file for every enum.

Comment: Thanks. Then I can also use the `using static` for the constants as Dimitry suggested since I will still need to reference the `constants' class if I want to use the constants from another file.

Comment: I can not use these enums from another file if I don't put them into a class.

Comment: Of course you can. Just be sure to make them public.

Comment: They are already public but I still get an error for missing directives (even if I include the enums separately by `using` keyword)